# Taking image of a webpage via a Linux (Ubuntu) server without UI installed

Tags: screenshot, html

I am looking for a webservice (API) or an application that I can install on my Linux Ubuntu server to take screenshot of webpages with a given URL.

I did not install any GUI on my server... Should I? Or is there a way around having to install a GUI?

Or is there a good API that I can use?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've got plenty of webservices to take screenshots of a given URL.

- http://browsershots.org/ but it's quite slow
- http://www.bounceapp.com/ quite fast, but it seems there is no API; you may still write some code to get the result screenshot (warning: it's medium-quality compressed JPEG)
- http://www.thumbalizr.com/ is a well known service and has an API

You may also use your own server-side software to generate screenshots. [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/screen-capture.html) is able to do so (including JS and SVG support) and, starting from version 1.5, no X server is needed.